# How to replace spaces in the object data?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I have stored days with timing in table. I want to add space between time and AM/PM how can I add a space. The data I have stored is given below

```
var dealerSchedule = {
        "monday": "09:10AM - 06:30PM",
        "tuesday": "09:10AM - 12:00PM",
        "wednesday": "09:10AM - 06:30PM",
        "thursday": "09:10AM - 06:30PM",
        "friday": "09:10AM - 06:30PM",
        "saturday": "10:15AM - 04:15PM",
        "sunday": "10:15AM - 04:15PM"
      };
```

Expected format:

```
var dealerSchedule = {
        "monday": "09:10 AM - 06:30 PM",
        "tuesday": "09:10 AM - 12:00 PM",
        "wednesday": "09:10 AM - 06:30 PM",
        "thursday": "09:10 AM - 06:30 PM",
        "friday": "09:10 AM - 06:30 PM",
        "saturday": "10:15 AM - 04:15 PM",
        "sunday": "10:15 AM - 04:15 PM"
      };
```

Comment: Have you tried something? Here are the steps: **1.** Iterate over object **2.** Replace `[AP]M` with ` $1`

Comment: If you stored the data in the first place, why can you not just change what you have stored?

Answer (score 0):

yes, check this fiddle

[enter link description here](http://jsfiddle.net/gurvinder372/akd8pj83/)

```
var dealerSchedule = {
        "monday": "09:10AM - 06:30PM",
        "tuesday": "09:10AM - 12:00PM",
        "wednesday": "09:10AM - 06:30PM",
        "thursday": "09:10AM - 06:30PM",
        "friday": "09:10AM - 06:30PM",
        "saturday": "10:15AM - 04:15PM",
        "sunday": "10:15AM - 04:15PM"
      };

for ( var day in dealerSchedule )
{
  dealerSchedule[ day ] = dealerSchedule[ day ].split( "AM" ).join( " AM" );
  dealerSchedule[ day ] = dealerSchedule[ day ].split( "PM" ).join( " PM" );
}
console.log( dealerSchedule );
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```js
var dealerSchedule = {
  "monday": "09:10AM - 06:30PM",
  "tuesday": "09:10AM - 12:00PM",
  "wednesday": "09:10AM - 06:30PM",
  "thursday": "09:10AM - 06:30PM",
  "friday": "09:10AM - 06:30PM",
  "saturday": "10:15AM - 04:15PM",
  "sunday": "10:15AM - 04:15PM"
};

Object.keys(dealerSchedule).forEach(function (day) {
  dealerSchedule[day] = dealerSchedule[day].replace(/([A-Z]+)/g, ' $1')
});

console.log(dealerSchedule);
```

Answer (score 0):

I see the others have been faster :) this one is mine

http://codepen.io/mkdizajn/pen/Bjyrax?editors=001

```
// get keys
var k = Object.keys(dealerSchedule);
// loop and replace
for(var i = 0; i < k.length; i++){
    dealerSchedule[ k[ i ] ] = dealerSchedule[ k[i] ].replace('PM', ' PM').replace('AM', ' AM') ;
}
```